# How to open camera with frame in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, camera

How to bound iPhone camera inside a frame like below image.

[image]

> Let the camera opens on full screen but the reading area will be only non blurred background in short i want to develop a screen shown in image.

I have tried this code but it is not working...

```
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
    picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
    picker.showsCameraControls = YES;
    picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    picker.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 10, 200, 20); // NOT WORKING !!!
    picker.toolbarHidden = YES;
    picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;
   // picker.delegate = delegate;

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0f, 50.0f);
    transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.2f, 1.2f);
    picker.cameraViewTransform = transform;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

how do i do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried anything for that, can you show ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom camera for that. As I can see in the image you need to scan barcode. For that you need to use

- AVCaptureSession
- AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

Comment: I do not want to scan barcode, image uploded just for ref.

Comment: Then create a custom Camera

Comment: Do u know any example related to my requirment?

Comment: See if it is working for you - https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Creating-a-Custom-Camera-View